# pre select a value from dropdown based on link clicked in core php

Tags: php, mysqli

need help.

when i click the link on page 1 the value should be pre selected in a drop down on page 2. how should i do it in core php? the drop down is listed from a database

Page1.

```
    <td>
    <a href="assign_student.php" class="link">Assign Student</a>
    </td>
```

Page2

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="classes">Select Class </label>
    <select name="classes" class="form-control">
    <?php foreach ($resultClass as $row): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row["class_name"]?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<?php foreach ($resultClass as $row): 
   if($row['id'] == 'Your desired id'){
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" selected><?php echo $row["class_name"]?>
    </option>
<?php } else{

    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row["class_name"]?>
    </option>
    <?php }endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass value in query string in link for example

```
<a href="assign_student.php?class=2" class="link">Assign Student</a>
```

then you will get that variable on Page 2 by

```
$_GET['class']
```

compare it in select > options like

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" <?php if($row['id'] == $_GET['class']) { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> ><?php echo $row["class_name"]?>
```

Best luck! :)

Comment: the link on page 1 is also in for loop. i cannot give it a name dynamically. and also the table is listed from a db.

Comment: So you should take a help of Jquery code for example, you can get a all attributes of the clicked URL by jquery code then set variable in query string accordingly and then go to page 2 with               
**window.location.href = "assign_student.php?class="+id;**